Proof of Theorem 13.4 in Jech's Set Theory
From chapter 13 in Jech's Set Theory:

Definition (Gödel Operations): $$
G_1(X, Y) = \{X, Y\},
$$
$$
G_2(X, Y) = X \times Y,
$$
$$
G_3(X, Y) = \varepsilon(X, Y) = \{(u, v) : u \in X \wedge v \in Y \wedge u \in v\},
$$
$$
G_4(X, Y) = X - Y,
$$
$$
G_5(X, Y) = X \cap Y,
$$
$$
G_6(X) = \bigcup X,
$$
$$
G_7(X) = \mathrm{dom}(X),
$$
$$
G_8(X) = \{(u, v) : (v, u) \in X\},
$$
$$
G_9(X) = \{(u, v, w) : (u, w, v) \in X\},
$$
$$
G_{10}(X) = \{(u, v, w) : (v, w, u) \in X\}.
$$


Theorem 13.4 (Gödel’s Normal Form Theorem). There exist operations $G_1, \ldots, G_{10}$ such that if $\varphi(u_1, \ldots, u_n)$ is a $\Delta_0$ formula, then there is a composition $G$ of $G_1, \ldots, G_{10}$ such that for all $X_1, \ldots, X_n$,
$$
G(X_1, \ldots, X_n) = \{(u_1, \ldots, u_n) : u_1 \in X_1, \ldots, u_n \in X_n \text{ and } \varphi(u_1, \ldots, u_n)\}.
$$
Proof: Case I. $\varphi(u_1, \ldots, u_n)$ is an atomic formula $u_i \in u_j$ ($i \neq j$). We prove this case by induction on $n$.
Case Ia. $n = 2$. Here we have
$$
\{(u_1, u_2) : u_1 \in X_1 \wedge u_2 \in X_2 \wedge u_1 \in u_2\} = \varepsilon(X_1, X_2)
$$
and
$$
\{(u_1, u_2) : u_1 \in X_1 \wedge u_2 \in X_2 \wedge u_2 \in u_1\} = G_8(\varepsilon(X_2, X_1)).
$$
Case Ib. $n > 2$ and $i, j \neq n$. By the induction hypothesis, there is a $G$ such that
$$
\{(u_1, \ldots, u_{n-1}) : u_1 \in X_1, \ldots, u_{n-1} \in X_{n-1} \wedge u_i \in u_j\} = G(X_1, \ldots, X_{n-1}).
$$
Obviously,
$$
\{(u_1, \ldots, u_n) : u_1 \in X_1, \ldots, u_n \in X_n \wedge u_i \in u_j\} = G(X_1, \ldots, X_{n-1}) \times X_n.
$$
[...]

The proof seems to be assuming that
$$(u_1,\ldots,u_{n-1},u_n) = ((u_1,\ldots,u_{n-1}), u_n),$$
this is, technically, not true. I know that it is assumed true in other areas of mathematics because both sets in questions are 'isomorphic', but I do not see why it can be assumed here.

Furthermore, if such 'trick' is allowed, couldn't we shorten the rest of the proof as follows?
Proof (?): for the case $I$, we use induction on the number of variables in the formula $\varphi$. Case Ia $(n=2)$ and Case Ib $(n>2$ and $i,j\ne n)$ are dealt as before.

Case Ic $(n>2$ and $i,j\ne 1)$: similar as the case before, yet multiplying by $X_1$ on the left.

Case Id $(n>2$ and $i=1,j=n)$: we wish to construct the set


$$\Big\{ (u_1,\ldots,u_n) : u_k\in X_k (\forall k) \land u_1\in u_n\Big\}$$
which is equal to
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
& \Big\{ (u_1,(\cdots),u_n) : u_1\in X_1\land (\cdots)\in X_2\times\cdots\times X_{n-1}\land u_n\in X_n \land u_1\in u_n\Big\}\\
=\ & G_{10}\left(\Big\{ (u_n,u_1, (\cdots)) : u_1\in X_1\land (\cdots)\in X_2\times\cdots\times X_{n-1}\land u_n\in X_n \land u_1\in u_n\Big\}\right)\\
=\ & G_{10}\left(\Big\{ (u_n,u_1) : u_1\in X_1\land u_n\in X_n \land u_1\in u_n\Big\}\times X_2\times\cdots\times X_{n-1}\right)
\end{split}
\end{equation}

$n$-tuples are defined in such a way that the equality holds, on page 7.
